# Calling a very simple function that lags

Tags: c

I created a simple function titled GetInput which prints "hello" if the user inputs "y" When I compile the program, and then enter "y" the program doesn't print "hello" unless I type in a couple of random characters then press enter. The image links are below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkwsq.png

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT9X8.png]

[1. The compiled code with the expected user input][2. The source code ]

Comment: Come on, post the code as text, not images links, and present your code correctly!

Comment: I'm extremely new to stackoverflow. Please elaborate on exactly how one should present code correctly.

Comment: The code should be posted as text so it can be easily copied to an editor and compiled or modified.  It is still in an image: if the bug is not immediately visible like this one, people on SO are not going to re-type it for testing.  As far as presentation, you are among the few who use indentation and spacing wisely, that's very good! just use fewer blank lines, eg single empty lines and none before `}` and it will be perfect.  For code to appear correctly, it must be indent by an extra 4 spaces at the beginning of each line, syntax coloring is automatic.  Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For: scanf("%c\n", &c);
Remove the '\n' and it should work fine.
Change to: scanf("%c", &c);